# How to install the newest version of a package with a specific tag?

Tags: python, torch, python-packaging

I'm trying to specify in the `requirements.txt` file that I want to install the newest version of a package, but only with a specific tag (the string after the `+` symbol, which is called a [local version label](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers) in [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/)).

Specifically, the `torch` package provides two versions, one for GPU+CPU and one for just the CPU. You can download the CPU-only version by appending the `+cpu` string to a full version string, e.g. `torch==1.10.0+cpu` (though you also need to use `--find-links` option).

I've read the entire PEP440 and [PEP508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/), and unless I misunderstood them, there is no way to ask for a specific tag without providing a specific version at the same time. I've tried to cheat my way with strings like `torch==1.*+cpu`, `torch>=1.0+cpu` or `torch==+cpu` but neither worked (and as far as I understand, PEP440 explicitly says they shouldn't work).

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? How can I automatically download the newest `torch` CPU-only version?

---

One somewhat promising solution I found is to use `--find-links` option and require `torch` without any version specifiers. In my empirical tests, the `+cpu` version was always the one that got downloaded. However, I couldn't find any information in PEP440 regarding the [relative ordering](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#summary-of-permitted-suffixes-and-relative-ordering) (besides the example) between versions `1.10.0` and `1.10.0+cpu`. I assumed my empirical tests were not deterministic and I discarded this solution.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you always want to pull the newest version? Typically you want to instead freeze a version to make sure that dependency updates are done in a controlled manner. I recently fixed a large number of requirement.txt files because aioredis 2.x changed the API significantly from 1.x but there was no pinned version in the requirements...

Comment: @vaizki I'm using `pip-compile` from [pip-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/) to freeze versions, but the syntax for `requirements.in` is the same and I didn't want to add too much information to the question. I assume (hopefully correctly) that a solution for `requirements.txt` will be the same for `requirements.in` and `pip-compile`.